# Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable: ActivityHistory.RelatedTo__c

Tags: apex, activities

I have created a field on Activity History when I am writing data in it. It is throwing this error.

> Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable: ActivityHistory.RelatedTo__c

```
for(ActivityHistory ah : listOfActivityHistory)
{
    rt = rt + ah.who.Name + ',';
}
listOfActivityHistory[0].RelatedTo__c = rt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActivityHistory` is a [read-only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm):

> This read-only object is displayed in a related list of closed
>   activities—past events and closed tasks—related to an object

so any modifications you want to do will have to be done through the `Event` or `Task`.